# How do I address the warning xcode error Thread 1: breakpoint 1.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I have been working on app following a few different tutorials. When I switch to a page (my FifthViewController) the simulator stops and gives me a thread1: breakpoint 1.2 error. I can't seem to find what exactly is the cause of this. Any clues?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "HomeModel.h"

@interface FifthViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, HomeModelProtocol>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *listTableView;    //Thread 1: breakpoint 1.2


@end
```

Comment: It's not an error, it's stopping there intentionally. Look at your breakpoints in the breakpoints tab in the left pane.

Comment: The breakpoints (blue arrows) are pointing at line 1 and 7.